# Add Dynamically A View in another View

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2.3

I have created a view

```
Ext.define("App.view.leaders.MyViewName", {
    extend: 'App.view.basePopup',
    xtype: 'MyViewName',
    config: <Ext.form.IPanel>{
        scrollable: 'vertical',           
        items: [
            {
                 xtype: 'fieldset',
                 title: 'Add New Auto Asset',
                 instructions: '<hr class="separate" />',
                 items: [
                     <Ext.field.ISelect>{
                         xtype: 'selectfield',
                         label: 'Borrower Position',
                         store: 'BorrowerPositionSelectorStore',
                     },
                     <Ext.field.ISelect>{
                         xtype: 'selectfield',
                         label: 'Asset Type',
                         store: 'AssetTypeSelectorStore',
                     },
                     {
                         xtype: 'textfield',
                         name: '',
                         label: 'Description'
                     },
                     {
                         xtype: 'numberfield',
                         name: '',
                         label: 'Value'
                     }                               
                 ]
             }
         ]
    }
});
```

and an instance of that view in a controller like:

```
var newObject = Ext.create("App.view.leaders.MyViewName");
```

and add it to another view dynamically like this:

```
var newAdd = this.getLeadDetail1003()
                 .down('leadDetail1003AssetsLiab')
                 .down('fieldset[itemId=AddCashAsset]');

newAdd.add(newObject);
```

but it is not added to the form! Can anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong or what I need to do now?

Comment: Please avoid similar and duplicate questions

Comment: If you know then please give link to me..
i am not get any useful link yet now..

Comment: please add the following and let me know the result:    console.log(this.getLeadDetail1003().down('leadDetail1003AssetsLiab').down('fieldset[itemId=AddCashAsset]'))

Comment: Its reference that particular fieldset And on console it display all property of that fieldset.
Yes one you have to know when i adding without making any view just write all view code in newAdd.add({
xtype:.....
many other...
}); 
it work.

Comment: Please post the code of the view you are trying to add. Also, is `newObject` created correctly?

Comment: @Anubis 2 I Posted the view.

Comment: What are those `<Ext.form.IPanel>`, `<Ext.field.ISelect>` in your view definition? I never saw that

Comment: These Are My Custom view.I created Custom componant.Treat it like simple xtype.
For <Ext.form.IPanel> treat it xtype:panel
and same as <Ext.form.ISelect> like xtype:selectfield.

Comment: @grishabh I can just guess what could be the error, if you don't have any errors in your console, maybe the view has been added but has no height, and so it is not displayed? Did you try to inspect the panel with developer tools? Also, I posted this question about your code if you are interested in answering it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26364497/what-is-the-purpose-of-classnames-in-angle-brackets-in-definitions

Comment: Yes View Is Added in the panel.
But it is not displaying....
So how can i display it...
@Anubis

Comment: Give more informations, I'm not here to do your job

Comment: I am not Force to any one to do my Job but here i want to take guidance.